# Why can't I paste multiple sudo commands in Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: bash, sudo, 22.04

I just installed Ubuntu Server 22.04 and SSHed in.  I'm not able to paste multiple sudo commands as I could with Ubuntu Server 20.04.  This feels to me like a security feature that I don't want.

Previously (before 22.04) I could manually enter `sudo -v` and then paste some `sudo` commands and I'd get:

```
user@host:~$ sudo -v
[sudo] password for user:
user@host:~$ sudo mkdir test
user@host:~$ sudo rm -r test
user@host:~$ ls
user@host:~$
```

Now, with 22.04, I get:

```
user@host:~$ sudo -v
[sudo] password for user:
user@host:~$ sudo mkdir test
sudo rm -r test
user@host:~$ ls
test
```

How can I change this behavior?

**Edit:**

After trying what's suggested in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1338648/295095), I still get the same results.  I did try pasting a second time after doing `bind 'set enable-bracketed-paste off'`.

```
user@host:~$ sudo -v
user@host:~$ bind 'set enable-bracketed-paste off'
user@host:~$ bind -v | grep bracketed
set enable-bracketed-paste off
user@host:~$ sudo -v
user@host:~$ sudo mkdir test
sudo rm -r test
user@host:~$ ls
test
user@host:~$
```

**Edit 2:**

I also ran `xterm` via `ssh` and X forwarding from my Mac and got the same results as a regular `ssh` connection.

Comment: If you want to use **multiple** commands via `sudo`, why not use `sudo -i` and then just enter the commands into root shell without prefixing them with `sudo`? Why do you want to prefix each command separately with `sudo`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pasted text in Gnome Terminal in 21.04 is always highlighted](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1334205/pasted-text-in-gnome-terminal-in-21-04-is-always-highlighted)

Comment: you just never got a prompt after the first sudo command

Comment: @raj, there are times when I want to paste multiple commands, some have `sudo` and some don't.

Comment: @vanadium, no I don't see the relevance of that question.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @raj because it is **best practice** to use sudo only when you need to run a command that actually needs the privileges. Elevating the whole shell to the root user is not good practice and increases the surface area for very costly mistakes.

Comment: @Nmath But I see no difference from safety point of view between `sudo X; sudo Y; sudo Z` and `X; Y; Z` typed in a root shell.

Comment: In that answer, it is indicated to change the paste behavior back to how it previously was.

Comment: @vanadium, I edited my question, showing that didn't work.

Comment: OK, I see. I cannot reproduce that issue on the desktop. Perhaps this is related to doing this over ssh. I retracted by close vote.

Answer (score 1):

It's due to the addition of `Defaults use_pty` in `/etc/sudoers`, comment out the line to revert to the previous behaviour.

Comment: This saved me. How is this not upvoted 100 times? Isn't Ubuntu the most popular Linux distribution in the world? How can hundreds if not thousands of people be impacted by this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Why not trying with

```
user@host:~$ sudo bash
```

and then write all your commands?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  That's covered in the comments, along with several reasons, "Why not."