# can not dump code in terminal anymore

Tags: command-line, python, 22.04, r

I do not use an IDE when I program (eg in R or python) but just use a text editor and copy code and then dump it in a terminal (guake - but I have the same issue with the stock terminal). This used to work fine and the code was executed line by line, but since I got a new laptop and updated to 22.04, it seems there is a limit on the number of lines/characters/commands the terminal can execute. It still works as it used to for smaller chunks of code, but not for long scripts...

Comment: This behavior changed as a security measure.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pasted text in Gnome Terminal in 21.04 is always highlighted](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1334205/pasted-text-in-gnome-terminal-in-21-04-is-always-highlighted)

Comment: No, it does not...

Comment: Yes, it does. It says how to change to the old behaviour.